# NoMethodError in ReportsController#import undefined method `original_filename' for "students.xlsx":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to import the student records but when i choose file it shows an error as 
`NoMethodError in ReportsController#import
undefined method`original_filename' for "students.xlsx":String`

and i tried to debbug this and I got

`[1] pry(#<ReportsController>)> Student.import(params[:file]) 
NoMethodError: undefined method`original_filename' for "import.xlsx":String
from /home/dk/import_multiple/school/app/models/student.rb:283:in `open_spreadsheet'`

This is my code:

**controller**

```
def importer      
  params[:role] == :guardian ? Guardian : Student
end

def import
  importer.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to import_reports_path, notice: "Students imported."
end
```

**student.rb**

```
COLUMNS_TO_STRING = ["batch_id", "class_roll_no","phone1","phone2"]  # and so on
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
  row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
  row = clean_for row, COLUMNS_TO_STRING
  record = Student.find_by(:id => row["id"],:batch_id =>    row["batch_id"],:class_roll_no => row["class_roll_no"],:phone1 =>  row["phone1"],:phone2 => row["phone2"]) || new
  record.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)
  record.save!  
 end
end
def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
 end
```

**guardian.rb**

```
COLUMNS_TO_STRING = ["student_id"] # and so on
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
  row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
  row = clean_for row, COLUMNS_TO_STRING
  guardian = Guardian.find_by(:id => row["id"],:student_id => row["student_id"]) || new
  guardian.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)
  guardian.save!
 end
end
def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
 end
```

**view**

```
<h1>IMPORT</h1>
<div class = "well">
    <p>
        <%= form_tag import_reports_path do %>
        <%= file_field_tag :file%>
        <br>
        <%= submit_tag "Import",class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
    </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Show the method `open_spreadsheet()`.

Comment: To the question body please.

Comment: @Зелёный check the question I've added `open_spreadsheet()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `form_tag` needs to know that it has a multipart file upload field in it - otherwise it will submit raw data, and not actually upload the file.

```
form_tag import_reports_path, multipart: true do
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like open_spreadsheet is expecting a File Object, not a String